# Set Alias on jpa specification on spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, criteria, specifications

How can set an alias on the id from the user and change it to "userId"?

Specification.java

```
    public static Specification<Subject> byColumnNameAndValueSubject(String value) {
        return new Specification<Subject>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Subject> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {

                Join<Subject, UsersSubjects> joinUsersSubjects = root.join("usersSubjects", JoinType.INNER);
                Join<UsersSubjects, User> joinUser = joinUsersSubjects.join("user", JoinType.INNER);

                Predicate predicateForData = criteriaBuilder.or(
                    criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("id").as(String.class), "%" +  value + "%"),
                    criteriaBuilder.like(joinUser.get("id").as(String.class), "%" + value + "%"));

                return criteriaBuilder.and(predicateForData);
            }
        };
    }
```

I want to searchable the id from user, Please help.

Comment: Why? What would it add?

Comment: I want to change or set an alias on the Id from the user table to "userId" instead of "id", I don't know if it's possible. @M.Deinum

Comment: What do you mean with alias here? It is totally unclear to me what you want to achieve? What do you think an alias is? Also the name of the field and the name of the column can be differnt and what you use here is the name of the field **not** the name of the column.

Comment: This is I want to achieve "SELECT id AS userId FROM user" I want to apply this as the temporary name on the predicate.

Comment: But why? What do you gain from specifying the alias. But you can use `alias` for that, something like `root.get("id").alias("userId")`.

Comment: I try that syntax `criteriaBuilder.like(joinUser.get("id").alias("userId"), "%" + value + "%"));` but it gives me an error `The method like(Expression<String>, String) in the type CriteriaBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (Selection<Object>, String)` also I add `.as(String.class)`

Comment: You can cast it back again to an expression. But still I don't see the added benefit of using an alias here. It only adds complexity without any gain or at least the gain isn't really clear from this.

Answer (score 0):

Surely this is easier: (I am assuming that a user can have many subjects and a subject can have many users)

```
@Id
@Column(name=”userId”)
Long id;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
  name = "user_subject", 
  joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userId"), 
  inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "subjectId"))
Set<Subject> subjects;
```